# SharedPreferences in separate file

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Can I place my model SharedPreferences and save/read methods in separate file? I want working whith SharedPreferences from app Activities. And how can I do it?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple ... Make it a static class ...

Add your methods that will retrieve information when needed such as

```
public void retrieveText(String textKey){

//Get info from the preference file.

}
```

I don't see the purpose of doing this when the Android itself provides a great means of utilizing SharedPreferences.
This is the way for you to go.

Hope it helps.

EDIT:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
```

Comment: Thanks, but in MySharedPreferences.java I can't get `SharedPreferences sharedPref;
 SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;`. This only for active activity. Or I must pass a reference on activity?

Comment: What do you mean its only for activity? You should be able to call the sharedpreference method in a .Java class.....

Comment: Ok, now I understand it. In MySharedPreferences.java I must `import android.app.Activity;` and `public class Settings MySharedPreferences Activity{...}`. Like this: [http://androidforums.com/application-development/41361-shared-preferences-help-needed.html]

Comment: Exactly..This is what you should have been doing before. =)

Comment: What are you trying to do EXACTLY? So i can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Each app has its unique sharedprefrences. Don't know what you mean by placing it in sperate file??

Sure you can have seperate methods to access SharedPrefrences within the app. You can't access the SharedPrefrence of the app A from app B.

Comment: I mean, in my single app I want create one separate file with single class - MySharedPreferences. There I want place model prefences and all logical operation with it. Any Activity must interaction from this class.

Comment: Can you give me little example, where, for instance, two activities interaction this it?